# Todavia se necesita los prefijos de navegador para las gradientes?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Es que estoy leyendo un libro de desarrollo web del 2017 y ahi me pide insertar los prefijos tal como:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, #FFFFFF, #666666);
```

y tengo la duda si en el 2020 sigue siendo necesario utilizar prefijos
Por cierto, el codigo es CSS

Answer (score 3):

Si nos guiamos por la gráfica que nos comparte [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-gradients) para el apartado de *CSS Gradients* tenemos que:

- El único navegador que al momento tiene soporte parcial es **Safari** en desktop
- A nivel móvil el único que también tiene soporte parcial es: **IOS Sfari**

Ambos en sus últimas versiones *al día de esta respuesta*.

Por otro lado aquellos que **no ofrecen soporte alguno**

- El único navegador **en móvil** que igualmente *a la fecha de esta respuesta* no tiene soporte alguno para esta propiedad es **Opera mini**

Fuera de estos 2 escenarios, los demás navegadores *en sus últimas versiones al día de esta respuesta* tienen soporte total.

Así que tienes 2 posibles respuestas:

- Si puedes asegurar que tus usuarios usarán en sus últimas versiones los navegadores que si ofrecen soporte entonces: no es necesario **que en ellos uses los prefijos para esta propiedad**
- Si dentro de tu target existen usuarios que usarán navegadores web que ofrecen soporte parcial (**insisto esto es aplicable al día de esta respuesta, pero en un futuro puede cambiar**) entonces si deberás agregar el uso de dichos prefijos.

**Recursos extra**

- [Especificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-3/#linear-gradients)

Answer (score 1):

Esos prefijos están creados para navegadores viejos es decir que si tu tienes navegador actualizado  sin prefijos va a funcionar el código, al contrario si tuvieras un navegador desactualizado no va a funcionar.

Los prefijos se usan para esos sistemas operativos que no soportan navegadores actuales.